# How to select /dev/random or dev/urandom in the code in Android?

Tags: java, random, android

When generating randomness using SecureRandom in Android, I want to select `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` as the seed source. It can be done in java.security file on Linux and Windows systems but there's not a java.security file on Android for now as much as I know. How can I do this selection?

Comment: If you are wondering how to do this, chances are that you are asking the wrong question. For nearly all applications, including cryptographic use, [`/dev/urandom` is great and possibly better](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This distinction doesn't exist under Android. Android did it right -- there's just a [single randomness source](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/SecureRandom.html) (unless the system opts to provide others) that provides randomness that is guaranteed to be cryptographically-secure. The platform ensures it's seeded, so there's nothing you need to do.

Comment: Thanks David. As you pointed out, it's written on the documentation that: "By default, instances of this class will generate an initial seed using an internal entropy source, such as /dev/urandom. This seed is unpredictable and appropriate for secure use." However what I'm planning to do is, to generate random numbers using SHA1PRNG with seeds from dev/random and dev/urandom, then check the obtained random numbers with randomness tests for comparison. As the documentation says a blurry exp like "from such as /dev/urandom" it's not clear which file is used generate the seed.

Comment: They will be the same because `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` use precisely the same mechanism. The only difference is that one blocks and the other doesn't when there's insufficient entropy -- but that can never happen on Android because Android seeds on startup. If you're trying to get at the internals, Android is a pure choice of platform do that because Android doesn't expose those internals. IMO, It only makes sense to analyze the difference on a platform that exposes both.

Comment: Thanks again David, I guess I'll need to build Android platform for both dev/random and dev/urandom as the selected seed source and then install on my device. Hope I can switch between dev/random and dev/urandom on the Android source code. It feels like Android will permit because both dev/random and dev/urandom exist on the Android system. On the other hand, trying on a different platform is another choice as you implied.

Comment: @RubiSharmax, don't do that!  Don't use /dev/random.  It is very likely that you should not be using /dev/random.  If you think you want to use it, odds are that you are confused.  (You never stated *why* you want to use /dev/random.)  /dev/random has no security advantages (for almost any application), and it has major performance disadvantages (it blocks; it depletes the entropy pool for others).  Search this site for more about /dev/random vs /dev/urandom.

Comment: @D.W.: Thanks for your recommendations. In fact I'm not planning to use dev/random as a seed source for a "real application". I know it depletes the entropy pool and blocks the system but I'm planning to test the randomness of dev/random and dev/urandom to check "how much" security advantage the former file provides over the latter one.

Comment: @RubiSharmax: There is no difference, so long as the entropy pool has ever been seeded since system startup. This is an intentional design property. `/dev/urandom` provides water, `/dev/random` provides holy water. If you discover a test that can tell one from the other, you will be famous.

Comment: To add some additional details about how android seeds /dev/urandom, it uses /dev/hw_random to seed /dev/urandom if it is available:   https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-4.4_r1/init/init.c#564

Comment: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6215969